# Indexing Error while trying to locate index where condition is satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to locate the indexes of a variable where a condition is given.

```
df.loc[df.variable[mask].diff() == 1]
```

But when I write it, it returns me an odd error

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

the `variable` is a series of boolean values and the `mask` is just an interval like this:

`mask = df.time_var.dt.date == datetime.date(2019, 10, 22)`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example (including a sample df) here to help us understand better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
print(df)
   # 0  1
# 0  1  2
# 1  3  4
# 2  5  6
print(df.loc[pd.Series([True, False, True])])
   # 0  1
# 0  1  2
# 2  5  6
print(df.loc[pd.Series([True, False])])
# Traceback (most recent call last):
# pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

`df.variable[mask].diff() == 1` is boolean Series which has different length than `df` so pandas can not decide which rows to choose. You probably can use this:

```
df.loc[(df.variable[mask].diff() == 1).index]
```